# AWS S3: Copy object fails when object name contains % with an error - Invalid copy source encoding

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a PHP script that copies files from one folder to another in an S3 bucket using the `copyObject` action. However, when a filename contains a percentage sign (%) this results in a 400 Bad Request error:

`<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Invalid copy source encoding</Message><ArgumentName>x-amz-copy-source</Argum (truncated...) InvalidArgument (client): Invalid copy source encoding - <Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Invalid copy source encoding</Message><ArgumentName>x-amz-copy-source</ArgumentName><ArgumentValue>x-amz-copy-source</ArgumentValue><RequestId>MJ6JPP4CJY87A4D2</RequestId><HostId>3iEO5xRKnpHhNAp+pTpGYUWgVEwP97k2qtQuJRTIiBKRL9KFGTMJLXUu8irha4PTtW2q3hWdxQA=</HostId></Error>'`

An example of a problematic filename is: ID!@£$%.jpg

Relevant PHP code:-

```
$filename = 'ID!@£$%.png';
$file_key = 'source/' . $filename;
$new_file_key = 'destination/' . $filename;
$bucketname = 'my-bucket';

$result = $client->copyObject(array(
  'Bucket'     => $bucketname,
  'Key'        => $new_file_key,
  'CopySource' => $bucketname."/".($file_key),
  'MetadataDirective' => 'COPY',
));
```

I also tried making a copy-object operation with aws cli and it worked fine for this filename:

```bash
aws s3api copy-object --copy-source my-bucket/source/ID!@£$%.png --key destination/ID!@£$%.jpg --bucket my-bucket
```

Could someone please help me to figure out what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you.